# Кабак и кабачок

Tags: этимология

Почему кафе, питейное заведение и овощ называются почти одинаково? Есть ли что-то общее между словами "кабак" и "кабачок"?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Скорее всего, эти слова просто созвучны, но оба имеют тюркский корень. Дело в том, что слово "капак" обозначает борьбу, соревнование. А в питейных заведениях нередко происходили драки.
Название же овоща произошло от тюркского "кабак" - "тыква", и является уменьшительной формой.

Answer (score 1):

Кабак - сниженное значение, пренебрежительное. Кабачок "Двенадцать стульев" - тёплая, уютная обстановка. Зависит от контекста.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего - случайное созвучие.
Кабачок (овощ) - безусловно восходит к тюркскому kabak - вид тыквы, скорее всего кабачок и есть.
А вот происхождение "кабак" неясно. Фасмер указывает на вероятное германское (нижненемецкое) происхождение слова. Восточные же версии объясняет несогласием некоторых авторов с немецкой версией. В целом же тюркская версия выглядит не очень убедительной в силу дальности значений гипотетических слов-источников.

Answer (score 0):

КАП

Лев Успенский  и голова.

http://www.pierbezuhov.ru/nauka/uspenskiy_lev/slovo_o_slovah/slovo_o_slovah9.html     РОДСТВЕННИКИ КАПИТАНА

«….Можно   предполагать,  что  те  римские  воины  и поселенцы, которые занесли
латинский  язык в древнюю Иберию и на берега Дуная, ушли из своего отечества
до того, как слово "тэста" окончательно взяло верх над "капут".

Дакия  (современная Румыния)  Присоединена к Римской империи при Траяне в 106 г. В 271 г. император Аврелиан решил вывести из Дакии римские войска и гражданское население на правый берег Дуная.

Просто возмущение захлестывает от вольного прозападного изложения. Лингвист, елы палы…  А ведь в румынском  и    слово   ţeastă   имеется.  Череп, башка. Skull.
В русском имеется созвучное слово тесто. Делать, которое, без башки не получится. И научиться делать тесто для выпечки хлеба нелегкое дело.

Кап березовый---скажет тоже от латыни.  Кап—круглый шарообразный нарост на дереве.

Фасмер-- "нарост на дереве, из которого делают разные вещи; прожилка; узел", вятск. (Васн.). По мнению Горяева (Доп. 1, 16), связано с Капать. Неприемлемо сближение с тюрк. kаb "сосуд" (см. Мi. ТЕl 1, 319). Рясянен (Festschrift-Vasmer 422) производит из тюрк. *kab, тур. kаv "трут"

С капать связь с точностью до наоборот. И пошло отсюда в тюркский.  А трут делают из гриба, чаги. Он растет на дереве и похож на кап.
Кабак, кабачок, кубок.

Капля---круглое и ничего более.  Маленький Шар.  Уменьшительный суффикс---ля. ОТ КАП.  И никакой связи с латинскими корнями??????  Есть связь прямая в латынь, а не наоборот!

Stillabunt---свободное падение…   НЕТ в латыни дословного понятия капли!!!!
Капель
Капать  от КАП.   КАП-КАП, капля за каплей.

Капуста- не только в славянских языках. По Фасмеру-- КАПУСТА. Общеслав. Этимология не установлена. Считается заимствованием, восходящим к контаминации лат. caput "голова" и compos(i)ta "составленная".

Слов нет, одни междометия….

Капуста –КАП+УСТА,  круглое съедобное.

В ирландском – cabáiste, корешок кап-с заменой буквы(произношение) видно, как и
В английском – cabbage, и уже просматривается кабак со значением много листьев, потом на растение типа кавун-тыква, семян много, а в кабаке от народа не продохнуть. И все ассоциативный русский язык. 
В венгерском – káposzta.
В мальтийском - kaboċċi
В итальянском – cavolo, после замен букв b-v   после всяческих метаморфоз  в виде возврата получился украинский  Кавун.
И интересная завязка на слово КАБАЛА. Не иначе, как кругом повязали и не вырваться.
В испанском— repollo,   от нашей русской Репы,  как результат классификации 17 века, репа и капуста одного вида растения.
В латыни это brassica?  И тут корешки видно , естественно скрытые,  ber и rassica.  «русские медведи»

В галисийском  тыква – Cabaza, а в баскском капуста - aza , а кабачок  не смешно становится(для историков и лингвистов) – kalabazin.
И по смыслу и по виду—колбаса и колобок в одном «флаконе». И только не надо петь песен про «народную» этимологию…   надоело. Залязнякам-на пенсию. 
Анализ словарей по полной программе и смысловой код. 
И что интересно, национальное блюдо—соленая капуста(квашенная)  превратилась во многих языках в KOL, через замену буквы из слова СОЛЬ.

Капище,  КАПЪ---круглый храм  В храмах античной Греции и Рима, а также в этрусской традиции капище заменяется целлами — специально построенными крытыми помещениями.
Целла-ассоциация целый. Келья—похоже от туда.

ФАСМЕР:  Слово: Капище Ближайшая этимология: "языческий храм". Из цслав., ст.-слав. капиште -- то же, от ст.-слав. капь ж. E‡dwlon "видение, призрак, образ", E„kиn "статуя, изображение" (Супр.). Дальнейшая этимология: Стар. заимств. из др.-чув. (дунайскобулг.) *k„р, соврем. чув. р„k, уйг. kер "форма, картина", стар.-тур. gib "картина", алт. kер, тел., шор. k„pk„, леб. k„pk„ "мера, образец, колодка". Из тюрк. заимств. мар. kар "тело, стан", коми kаb "колодка", также венг. keґр "картина" (см. Гомбоц 93 и сл.); ср. Паасонен, WuS 6, 142 и сл.; Миккола, WuS 6, 144; Младенов 231; RЕS I, 48 и сл.; Брюкнер, KZ 48, 189 и сл.; Гуйер, LF 47, 52. Против, без основания, см. Ильинский, ИОРЯС 23, I, 149 и сл. Устарели и.-е. сравнения: с Копаґть, греч. KТptw, вопреки Мерингеру (IF 18, 280); ср. также Мейе, МSL 14, 339, а также с греч. Sk©poj †KlЈdoj, SkhpЈnion "посох, скипетр", SkБptron -- то же, лат. sсѓрus "посох, стержень", д.-в.-н. skaft "стержень" (вопреки Сольмсену (Beitr. 206 и сл.), Бернекеру (1, 468): "если не заимств."). Уже Горяев (ЭС 132) сравнивал с русск.-цслав. Кыпь "imago" (Мi. LР 328).

Вообще, читая Фасмера, складывается впечатление, что русского языка и в помине никогда не было, по крайней мере, до 9-века.  Все слова у него происхождением тюркские, польские, греческие, немецкие да латинские в большинстве своем. Да и  суффиксы он просто игнорирует.

Гульбище, кровища, толковище, чудовище, ручища…..      суффикс---ища, ище----что-то большое, со значением много!!!!! КАПИЩЕ --- ЕЩЁ!!!!  Круглое,большое. Это может относиться как к основанию, так и к самому идолу, бревну.  Культ круга, колеса. Уж какая там картина. И причем тут церковнославянский, если слову несколько тысяч лет--неолит?

Слово: Капа Ближайшая этимология: "шапка", др.-русск. *Капа, Накапка "женское покрывало на голову в виде фаты", грам. 1499 г., 1503 г. и т. д. (Срезн. II, 292), укр. Капа. Вероятно, через польск. kара из лат. сарра; см. Мi. ЕW 111; Бернекер 1, 485. Согласно последнему, сюда же следует отнести и др.-русск. Капа "мера зерна" (Срезн. I, 1192).

КАП—корень, опять же шапка-круглая.

Каплун—петух без яиц!!!11  Кап-круглое, луна---смерть.

Капкан --петля круглая. Которую хан на зверя ставит.

Получается, что корень КАП   идет не от латинского, а наоборот из русского в латинский,  причем скорее всего в виде головного убора   CAPPA, где уже потом приобретает смысл головы с добавлением суффикса  CAPUT. А дальше начинает множиться и, в конце концов,  в виде массы слов возвращается в русский:

Капитан, капитал, и пр.

Купаться и купель все от той же капли и кап кап.

Слово: Капелюх Ближайшая этимология: "шапка, фуражка, малахай, шапка с ушами", зап., южн. (Даль), укр. Капелюх. Через польск. kapelusz, диал. kареluсh из ит. сарреlluссiо; см. Бернекер 1, 484; Преобр. I, 295.

Слов слишком много с корнем кап и его видоизменениями, одно ясно, что латынь с ее латинским шрифтом имела хождение наравне  со славянской азбукой и не так уж и стара по сравнению с русским, если не моложе…

Великая путаница имеет быть место в написании и произношении.

Comment: Ээээ....
Это вы о чем?!
так, вкратце, если не трудно.

Comment: оооо, а вы про что вкратце хотеть изволите?